# Pythonic way to find 2 items from two lists existing in a another list

Tags: python, list

I have some twitter data and I split the text into those with happy emoticons and sad emoticons elegantly and pythonically like so:

```
happy_set = [":)",":-)","=)",":D",":-D","=D"]
sad_set = [":(",":-(","=("]

happy = [tweet.split() for tweet in data for face in happy_set if face in tweet]
sad = [tweet.split() for tweet in data for face in sad_set if face in tweet]
```

This works, however, it could be the case that both an emoticon from the `happy_set` and `sad_set` could be found in a single tweet. What is the pythonic way to ensure that the `happy` list only contains emoticons from the `happy_set` and vice versa?

Comment: You want "only happy" in `happy`. "only sad" in `sad` and discard "both happy and sad" ?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, that exactly

Comment: Could do a set intersection on `{happy,sad}_set` and the tweet?

Comment: For such a question you should provide a [MCVE example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it might help for for testing and disambiguating the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using sets, specifically `set.isdisjoint`. Check to see if the set of tokens in a happy tweet is disjoint from `sad_set`. If so, it definitely belongs in `happy`:

```
happy_set = set([":)",":-)","=)",":D",":-D","=D"])
sad_set = set([":(",":-(","=("])

# happy is your existing set of potentially happy tweets. To remove any tweets with sad tokens...
happy = [tweet for tweet in happy if sad_set.isdisjoint(set(tweet.split()))]
```

Comment: this throws the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdisjoint'

Answer (score 1):

I would use lambdas :

```
>>> is_happy = lambda tweet: any(map(lambda x: x in happy_set, tweet.split()))
>>> is_sad = lambda tweet: any(map(lambda x: x in sad_set, tweet.split()))

>>> data = ["Hi, I am sad :( but don't worry =D", "Happy day :-)", "Boooh :-("]
>>> filter(lambda tweet: is_happy(tweet) and not is_sad(tweet), data)
['Happy day :-)']
>>> filter(lambda tweet: is_sad(tweet) and not is_happy(tweet), data)
['Boooh :-(']
```

That will avoid creating intermediary copies of `data`.

And if `data` is really big you can replace `filter` by an `ifilter` from the package `itertools`to get an iterator instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you are looking for?

```
happy_set = set([":)",":-)","=)",":D",":-D","=D"])
sad_set = set([":(",":-(","=("])

happy_maybe_sad = [tweet.split() for tweet in data for face in happy_set if face in tweet]
sad_maybe_happy = [tweet.split() for tweet in data for face in sad_set if face in tweet]

happy = [item for item in happy_maybe_sad if not in sad_maybe_happy]
sad = [item for item in sad_maybe_happy if not in happy_maybe_sad]
```

For `happy...` and `sad...`, I stick with the list solution as the item's order is maybe relevant. If not, it might be better using [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for performances though. Is additions, sets already provides the [basic sets operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) (unions, intersection, etc.)